# Printing a 2D char array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char

so I have a problem with my code which I can't pinpoint. Simply put, I want to print out the contents of a 2D char array in c++ in a grid format. My code is the following (keep in mind that I dont want to change the structure of my code just find why I am not getting the desired result):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void drawBoard(char board[3][4])
{
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
    {
        if ((i % 4) == 1 || (i % 4) == 2)
        {
            cout << " " << board[i][j] << " |";
        }
        else if ((i % 4 == 3))
        {
            cout <<  " " + board[i][j] << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "---+---+---" << endl;
            j += 1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char board[3][4] = { {' ', ' ', ' ', '\0'}, {' ', ' ', ' ', '\0'}, {' ', 
    ' ', ' ', '\0'} };
    drawBoard(board);

    cin.get();
}
```

What I would expect for this to give me is a basic tic-tac-toe grid with blank spaces where the X's and O's go. Instead what I get is a grid as expected with random characters placed in some of the squares and no matter how much tweaking I do gives the same or a similar result but I don't understand why. Any help would be appreciated (Also preferably not including anything beyond basic c++ like functions, loops etc since I haven't learnt those yet and we can't use them in our assignment even if we know them).

Comment: Valid first index into `board[3][4]` is 0 through 2. You use a number as high as 11. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: Indeed, had a go at it and ended up with this:
`void drawBoard(char board[3][4])
{
 int j = 0;
 
 for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
 {
  if ((i % 3) == 0 || (i % 3) == 1)
  {
   cout << " " << board[j][i % 3] << " |";
  }
  else if ((i % 3 == 2))
  {
   cout <<  " " + board[j][i % 3] << endl;
   if (j < 2)
   {
    cout << "---+---+---" << endl;
    j += 1;
   }
  }
 }
}`

Rest is the same. Most of it prints correctly apart from the last column which remains blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the array range:

```
char board[3][4]
```

Then you have:

```
board[i][j]  ->  board[1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11][j]
```

No matter what `i%4` is, what is put in `board` is `i` not `i%3`.

Use either structures:

```
for i
   for j
      board[i][j]
```

or

```
for i
   ((char*)board)[i]
```

I have edited your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void drawBoard(char board[3][4])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        if(i%4!=3)
        {
            cout<<" "<<board[i/4][i%4]; // board[0 to 2][0 to 2, 3 skept]
            if(i%4<2)
                cout<<" |";
        }
        else
        {
            if(i/4<2)
                cout<<endl<< "---+---+---";
            cout<<endl; // new line
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char board[3][4] = { {'x', 'o', 'x', '\0'}, {'o', 'x', 'x', '\0'}, {'o', 
    'o', 'x', '\0'} };
    drawBoard(board);

    cin.get();
}
```

---

Results:

```
 x | o | x
---+---+---
 o | x | x
---+---+---
 o | o | x
```

Comment: Indeed, had a go at it and ended up with this: `void drawBoard(char board[3][4]) { int j = 0; for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { if ((i % 3) == 0 || (i % 3) == 1) { cout << " " << board[j][i % 3] << " |"; } else if ((i % 3 == 2)) { cout << " " + board[j][i % 3] << endl; if (j < 2) { cout << "---+---+---" << endl; j += 1; } } } }` Rest is the same. Most of it prints correctly apart from the last column which remains blank.

Comment: @AlkamlBanalkaml, if `i` counts from 0 to 9 then why `board[3][4]` not `board[3][3]` ?? For `board[3][4]`, what does `board[j][i % 3]` mean? it means `((char*)board)[j*4+i%3]`. Be careful of index positions.